# How to draw a window at an angle?

Tags: c#, winforms, window, angle

Such as this [image: angled window].

Comment: @RoyGoode Ooh, can I borrow that link? I can use it!

Comment: There is at least 2 approaches that I think of:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows doesn't implement this.  Best you could do is use the Region property to give a rectangular window an arbitrary shape.  Won't look great, regions are not anti-aliased.  Displaying the content on an angle is up to you, Graphics.RotateTransform() for example.  Getting liability insurance for the user's neck cramp claims is also up to you.